# how to use tags manager?

Tags: jquery, tags

can anyone show me a simple implementation of this tags manager to make it work on a simple html file?

http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager

i did try to implement it myself as shown  below but i'm not able to get it to work.

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>tags example</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-tagmanager.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/css/bootstrap-tagmanager.css"></script>
     <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tagsManager"/>

 <script src="assets/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/controllers.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript">                    </script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(".tagManager").tagsManager({
         prefilled: ["Pisa", "Rome"],
         CapitalizeFirstLetter: true,
         preventSubmitOnEnter: true,
         typeahead: true,
         typeaheadAjaxSource: null,
         typeaheadSource: ["Pisa", "Rome", "Milan", "Florence", "New York", "Paris",      "Berlin", "London", "Madrid"],
         delimeters: [44, 188, 13],
         backspace: [8],
         blinkBGColor_1: '#FFFF9C',
         blinkBGColor_2: '#CDE69C',
         hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagListA'
     });
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: your jQuery selector should be `$('.tagsManager')` not `$('.tagManager')`.

Comment: hi i tried changing that alraedy but it still couldn't work. are you able to show me how you got it to work by attaching ur codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vt2z4/) out, you have also not added hidden field hiddenTagListA

Change your code from this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-tagmanager.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/css/bootstrap-tagmanager.css"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(".tagManager").tagsManager({
     prefilled: ["Pisa", "Rome"],
     CapitalizeFirstLetter: true,
     preventSubmitOnEnter: true,
     typeahead: true,
     typeaheadAjaxSource: null,
     typeaheadSource: ["Pisa", "Rome", "Milan", "Florence", "New York", "Paris",      "Berlin", "London", "Madrid"],
     delimeters: [44, 188, 13],
     backspace: [8],
     blinkBGColor_1: '#FFFF9C',
     blinkBGColor_2: '#CDE69C',
     hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagListA'
 });
</script>
```

to this

```
 <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-tagmanager.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-tagmanager.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $(".tagsManager").tagsManager({
     prefilled: ["Pisa", "Rome"],
     CapitalizeFirstLetter: true,
     preventSubmitOnEnter: true,
     typeahead: true,
     typeaheadAjaxSource: null,
     typeaheadSource: ["Pisa", "Rome", "Milan", "Florence", "New York", "Paris",      "Berlin", "London", "Madrid"],
     delimeters: [44, 188, 13],
     backspace: [8],
     blinkBGColor_1: '#FFFF9C',
     blinkBGColor_2: '#CDE69C',
     hiddenTagListName: 'hiddenTagListA'
  });
});
 </script>
```

Comment: OMG. it worked! thanks so much! now im going to play around with it. THANKS

Comment: is it possible to give the tags a location to be append to? In that they seem to be just getting added directly to the left of the input box, would it be possible to append them to another text box which would act as a container for all tags created???